# How can I create a live sub-collection based on a predicate?

Tags: java, collections, functional-programming

**Background**

I have an interface

```
public interface ThingRegistry {

    public Set<Thing> getAllThings();
    public Set<Thing> getAllThingsWithProperty(String property);
}
```

And an implementation

```
public class MemoryThingRegistry {
    private final Set<Thing> things = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Thing> getAllThings() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.things);
    }

    public Set<Thing> getAllThingsWithProperty(final String property) {
        return this.things.stream().filter((thing) -> thing.hasProperty(property)).collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

- The Set returned by `getAllThings()` will reflect any changes made within my registry
- However, the Set returned by `getAllThingsWithProperty()` will not reflect these changes

**The Question**

Is there any way using standard java libraries, or some incredibly common third party library, to make the return value of `getAllThingsWithProperty()` to be a "live" sub `Set`? I.E. it "backed by" the original `Set` but reapplies the `Predicate` each time its accessed? Preferably something that could apply to any `Collection` as I have another Registry interface which uses a `List`.

I know I could write my own `Set` implementation but would prefer to avoid that.

Comment: Writing your own ```Set``` implementation sounds like a big thing, but you could simply wrap the standard HashSet in a class which also utilises the Observer pattern. That way you could always update your subset "automatically" when the main set changes. But obviously you'd also have to use some means of synchronisation to make it threadsafe (if needed).

Comment: @geanakuch I realise that the implementation would start off small, but it's mostly just that I suspect this is a common problem so was wondering if there was an out-of-the-box solution.
It would be annoying if I had to keep re-writing the same thing on future projects. Especially since there is room for a lot of complexity E.G. eager caching (as you suggested) or lazy caching

Comment: Yup, I hear you ;-) These things get out of hand pretty fast. But then it might be better to switch to immutable classes, then you wouldn't have to handle data that changes while you're working on it at all. But that's just me, I fear I've strayed far enough from the original question...

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a method that returns a `Set<Thing>`. You can write a method that returns a `Supplier<Set<Thing>>`. And each time you want to get the current `Set`, you call that `Supplier`'s `get()` method.

```
public Supplier<Set<Thing>> getAllThingsWithProperty(final String property) {
    return () -> this.things.stream().filter((thing) -> thing.hasProperty(property)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's fairly straightforward to use `AbstractSet` to bring up a `Set` implementation. All you need to do is to implement the `size` and `iterator` methods. You're using streams already, so you can just use streams to implement these methods:

```
public static <E> Set<E> filteredSet(Set<E> set, Predicate<? super E> pred) {
    return new AbstractSet<>() {
        public int size() {
            return (int) set.stream().filter(pred).count();
        }

        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return set.stream().filter(pred).iterator();
        }
    };
}
```

This is a fully functional, read-only `Set`. It provides a "live view" of the backing set, since its elements are streamed and filtered on every operation.

This is workable for sets with small numbers of elements, but it can slow down noticeably as the number of elements grows. For example, the `contains` method potentially iterates the entire set and is thus O(N). You could override the `contains` method to delegate directly to the backing set. This will reduce the time complexity to whatever the underlying set provides -- for `HashSet`, this is O(1) -- but there are some subtleties involved.

To make the set read-write, you'd need to implement the `add` method and reimplement the iterator so that it supports the `remove` method. But you were returning unmodifiable sets in the first place, so maybe you don't need that.

If you need to do something similar with `List`, take a look at `AbstractList`. It's fairly straightforward. Or use `AbstractCollection` to wrap any collection the same way as shown here with `AbstractSet`.

Comment: The performance of the filtered set will increase significantly if you add a method like `@Override @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") public boolean contains(Object o) { return set.contains(o) && pred.test((E)o); }` (the unchecked cast is justified due to the preceding `set.contains(o)` test). If you do the same thing with a `List`, it should extend `AbstractSequentialList` but too many developers assume random access without checking, so I wouldn’t recommend filtered live list views…